# Warning: implode() [function.implode]: Invalid arguments passed in [path]/clancp.php on line 1394

Tags: php, mysql, implode

## Warning: implode() [function.implode]: Invalid arguments passed in [path]/clancp.php on line 1394

// ###################### Start Manage Clan Invites Page #######################

if ($_REQUEST['do'] == 'manageinvite')

{

```
if (count($clan['invite']) == 0)
{
    // No invites
    eval(standard_error(fetch_error('rpg_clan_no_invites_sent')));
}

$usernames_query = $db->query_read("
    SELECT `rpgname`, `userid`, `clanid`
    FROM `" . TABLE_PREFIX . "rpg_user`
    WHERE `userid` IN(" . implode(', ', $clan['invite']) . ")
");
while ($userinfo = $db->fetch_array($usernames_query))
{
    $checked = '';
    if ($userinfo['clanid'] > 0)
    {
        // In clan
        $checked = ' checked="checked"';
    }
    
    // Fetch template for each user
    eval('$invitedbit .= "' . fetch_template('rpg_clan_user_invitedbit') . '";');
}
$db->free_result($usernames_query);
```

Please help I'm new at this. I need to find the problem.

Line 1394 ###### WHERE `userid` IN(" . implode(', ', $clan['invite']) . ")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$clan['invite']` is not an array. `var_dump` it to see what it is.

FYI, `count($clan['invite'])` will evaluate to 1 if it's not an array.

Comment: I'm sorry i'm noob a this: what is var_dump? and how do I set it up?

Comment: bool(false)
Warning: implode() [function.implode]: Invalid arguments passed in [path]/clancp.php on line

Comment: @AnimeTribes: `var_dump` is a function, as I'm sure you've discovered by now. It's telling you that your variable is `false` which confirms my suspicions that it's not an array. Where's that variable coming from? How do you initialize `$clan`?

Comment: Thank you all, I have found the solution.